# object is null when setting checked state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

So i have a page that has a couple of jQuery plugins. Among other things i have the multiselect toolbar, a pretty sweet plugin. problem is that when i load up the page in internet explorer the page breaks. i've been able to determine that the problem occurs when i try to set some attributes to some elements that i have dynamically generated.

here is the code for generating the elements:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~")' + 'Ticket/GetTvrtke',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById("header_tvrtka_holder").innerHTML = data;

                var tvrtke = data.split(", ");

                for (var i = 0; i < tvrtke.length; i++) {
                    document.getElementById("KlijentMultiSelect").innerHTML +=
                        "<option value=\"" + tvrtke[i] + "\" id=\"" + tvrtke[i] + "\" >" + tvrtke[i] + "</option>";
                }

                $("#KlijentMultiSelect").multiselect({
                    selectedText: "",
                    height: 125,
                    minWidth: 650,
                    noneSelectedText: 'Izaberite željene tvrtke:'
                });
            }
        });
```

the function gets  the correct data and generates the options, and then i activate the plugin to render the new dropdown menu with checkboxes.

problem is that afterwards i have this code:

```
           var tvrtke = document.getElementById("header_tvrtka_holder").innerHTML.split(", ");

            for (var i = 0; i < tvrtke.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("ui-multiselect-" + tvrtke[i]).checked = true;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < tvrtke.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("ui-multiselect-" + tvrtke[i]).setAttribute("onclick", "ChangeTextKlijent()");
            }
```

here i am trying to set the checkbox values to true and add an on click event to the input element, but then visual studio sends me the error message from the title. in firefox, everything works great but IE is a whole different story.

anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Doing `document.getElementById("KlijentMultiSelect").innerHTML +=` in a for loop is bad for performance. Also not all browsers support adding options with innerHTML. Remove the element look up to outside the loop. And you are using jQuery, why mix DOM and jQuery. Pick one.

Comment: @epascarello Soooooooooo many good points

Comment: That message means that document.getElementById cant find an element with id `"ui-multiselect-" + tvrtke[i]` can you confirm you really have an options with ids like that in IE?

Comment: the switch to jquery did the trick, so thank you. ill keep this in mind while refactoring and adding code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched so that my code looks like this:

```
var tvrtke = document.getElementById("header_tvrtka_holder").innerHTML.split(", ");

$.each(tvrtke, function (index, value) {
    $("#KlijentMultiSelect").append("<option value=\"" + value + "\" id=\"" + value + "\" >" + value + "</option>");
});
```

and now it works.